# How do i detect blur/unfocus on autocomplete items in jQueryUI?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using the Autocomplete widget in jQueryUI and I now try to customize it a bit.

I would like to highlight the hovered item in the autocomplete list in a custom way. In the sample code below I change the font to bold by using the `focus` event and look up the selected element and finally modifies the style for that element.

Before changing the hovered item to bold I make sure to reset all other items to normal font (otherwise the previous items will remain bold when hovering over next).

It works partially, but I don't like my solution (I find it a little bit "ugly"). One problem is that if I move the mouse pointer outside the list it won't detect it, and the last item will remain bold. See picture:

[image]

I'm stuck here... How can I detect the blur event in a better way and remove the bold from the last hovered item? Heres my sample code:

```html
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script>
        $( function() {
            var availableTags = [
                "ActionScript", "AppleScript", "Asp", "BASIC", "C", "C++", "Clojure", "COBOL", "ColdFusion",
                "Erlang", "Fortran", "Groovy", "Haskell", "Java", "JavaScript", "Lisp", "Perl", "PHP", "Python",
                "Ruby", "Scala", "Scheme"
            ];

            $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
            source: availableTags,
            focus: function( event, ui ) {
                // Reset all list item fonts
                $(".ui-menu-item-wrapper").css("font-weight", "normal");

                // Find the element selected and make it bold
                selector = ".ui-menu-item-wrapper:contains(" + ui.item.label +")";
                $(selector).css("font-weight", "bold");
                },
            });
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <div class="ui-widget">
        <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
        <input id="tags">
    </div>
    
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following CSS Example.

```js
$(function() {
  var availableTags = [
    "ActionScript", "AppleScript", "Asp", "BASIC", "C", "C++", "Clojure", "COBOL", "ColdFusion",
    "Erlang", "Fortran", "Groovy", "Haskell", "Java", "JavaScript", "Lisp", "Perl", "PHP", "Python",
    "Ruby", "Scala", "Scheme"
  ];

  $("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
  });
});
```

```css
.ui-autocomplete .ui-menu-item .ui-state-active {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
```

Autocomplete uses Menu and Menu uses `ui-state-active` for the items. With the correct CSS Selector, you can make the highlighted items Bold.